# Java nested lists in map returns an error when passing a list of lists to Map values

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, hashmap, nested-lists

I've a class called ZipClass which basically just holds two static methods:
 - ZipToList() to put two lists of a same size into lists of lists; and
 - ZipToMapList() to put list of values as keys and lists of lists as values to the keys.

First method works fine:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> zipToList(List<T> list1,List<T> list2)
{
    List<T> tuple = new ArrayList<>(); //a list for pair of values from from same columns (fields)
    List<List<T>> tuples = new ArrayList<>(); // a list of lists
    if(list1.size() == list2.size()) //check that size of lists the same
    {        
        for(int idx = 0; idx < list1.size(); idx ++ )
        {
            //feed tuple with the pair of values
            tuple.add(list1.get(idx));
            tuple.add(list2.get(idx));
            //feed list of lists with the list of paired values
            tuples.add(copyList(tuple));
            //clear pair for the next iteration
            tuple.clear();
        }
    } else System.out.println("Lists must be of same size");

    return tuples;
}
```

My second method:

```
public static <K,V extends List<?>> Map<K,List<?>> zipToMapList(List<K> keys,List<List<?>> values)
{
    Map<K,List<?>> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(int idx = 0; idx < keys.size(); idx ++ )
    {
        dataMap.put(keys.get(idx), values.get(idx));
    }
    return dataMap;
}
```

I've two lists which hold Integer values: values1 and values2
and I've list of keys which holds String values: keys
when I try to print the content of dataMap:
    System.out.println(zipToMapList(keys,zipToList(values1,values2)));
there is an error message:

```
The method zipToMapList(List<K>, List<List<?>>) in the type ZipClass is not applicable for the arguments (List<String>, List<List<Integer>>)
```

zipToList() method works just fine but I can't understand what is exactly happening in my second method, I guess it's something to do with:

```
<K,V extends List<?>>
```

So "K" is a generic reference type for keys. V extends List and presumes to hold any type of List and an inner  relates to any type for List.
After googling I realize that this is probably an illegal way but can't understand why.
Can anyone please explain why? and what is the way to overcome this problem?

Many thanks!

Comment: You are not using `V` anywhere in `zipToMapList`, so why do you need it at all?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using the generic type parameter `V` anywhere in your `zipToMapList` method, I suggest using it for the element type of the `List`:

```
public static <K,V> Map<K,List<V>> zipToMapList(List<K> keys,List<List<V>> values)
{
    Map<K,List<V>> dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(int idx = 0; idx < keys.size(); idx ++ )
    {
        dataMap.put(keys.get(idx), values.get(idx));
    }
    return dataMap;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that one! But what If I do `<K, V extends List<?>>` and then `Map<K,ArrayList<?>>`. In this case I'm using ArrayList of V List type but it still results to the same error?

Comment: @Vlad I believe you shouldn't be using a wild card. Instead of `<K, V extends List<?>>` you can write `<K, E, V extends List<E>>` and then you can use `Map<K,ArrayList<E>>`. Of course, I still don't see what you need `V` for.

Comment: was just learning this topic and playing around with different ways of how generics can come in to play. Thanks very much for help Eran!